# Can't launch PHP background script

Tags: php

I am trying to build a backup app for my website, and as part of that, I want to launch a PHP script in the background.  That way I don't have to worry about it timing out.  The strange part is that it works fine on my local computer, but when I copy it to my Hostgator website, it goes crazy.

I've cobbled together a simple example...

First, I created a simple PHP script:

```
<?php
    echo 'Current PHP version: ' . phpversion() . "\n";
    echo 'Now:       '. date('Y-m-d') ."\n";
    echo "This is created by phpbg-back.php\n\n";
    echo "Current file: " . __FILE__;
?>
```

I can run that script by SSH'ing into my host and running this command:

```
# php phpbg-back.php 
Current PHP version: 5.4.36
Now:       2015-01-16
This is created by phpbg-back.php

....
```

So, the script seems to work fine.  Now, I created a page that will launch the script as a background process:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET["schedule"])) {  ?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Scheduling PHP Process</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Schedule....</h1>
        <p>We are scheduling the process right now.  Here is the output:</p>
        <pre><?php
            $command = "php phpbg-back.php > phpbg-out.txt 2>&1 &";
            echo "Command: " . $command . "\n";
            echo shell_exec($command);
        ?></pre>

        <a href="phpbg-front.php">Go back to the front page and check the output</a>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
    } else {
        echo "Invalid -- the page should have the schedule parameter set.\n\n";
        echo "Current file: " . __FILE__;
    }
?>
```

Finally, I created a nice front page that should be able to view the output:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example: PHP Background Process</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Example: PHP Background Process</h1>

        <h2>Schedule</h2>
        <p>Click this link to schedule the background process to run</p>
        <a href="phpbg-sched.php?schedule=true">Schedule</a>

        <h2>Output</h2>

        <?php if(file_exists('phpbg-out.txt')) { ?>
            <pre><?= file_get_contents('phpbg-out.txt') ?></pre>
        <?php } else { ?>
            <p>No output file found</p>
        <?php } ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that when the script runs through this page it seems to totally ignore the script that I am passing to it.  It runs the current PHP page instead.  So, the output looks more like this (phpbg-out.txt):

```
Content-type: text/html^M
^M
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Scheduling PHP Process</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Schedule....</h1>
        <p>We are scheduling the process right now.  Here is the output:</p>
        <pre>Command: php phpbg-back.php > phpbg-out.txt 2>&1 &
</pre>

        <a href="phpbg-front.php">Go back to the front page and check the output</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've tried all sorts of things to get it to work.  I tried adding bash -c in front of the command.  I've used the -f switch to make it pick the PHP script.  I'm not sure what else to try.

Comment: Do you have the rights to perform this tasks/actions? Root or shared server?

Comment: try `php phpbg-back.php  2>&1 >>  phpbg-out.txt` to see what message `shell_exec` return.

Comment: @TopQuestions  As for rights, it seems to allow me to execute shell commands like tar or cp.  I have SSH access to the server.  It is a shared server, so I don't have root access.

Comment: @jsxqf  I did try that, and it does the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shell command will not work if you're on a shared server. If you are on a dedicated machine/VM, try using:

```
$output = '';
shell_exec($command, $output);
echo $output;
```

This will print the output of the command you are trying to run, which will hopefully give you some clues.

Comment: I am on a shared server.  Is there a way to accomplish this or is there no way to run long-running processes in the background on a shared server?

Comment: You cannot run any shell commands on a shared server. Allowing shell commands on a shared box would introduce a myriad of security issues. If you want command-line control, I recommend a dedicated server, or a virtual private server (VPS).

Comment: I just want to be able to automate some management tasks such as backing up and deploying updates to my applications.  I guess I'll just have to rethink what I am doing.  I am not sure that I am quite ready to go bite off the cost of a dedicated server or VPS.

Answer (score 2):

> $command = "php phpbg-back.php > phpbg-out.txt 2>&1 &";

There are multiple issues here. The first is that you assume that the web PHP is running in the same context (same root filesystem, same $PATH environment variable, same CWD) as your ssh session - this is not a valid assumption.

The next issue is that you assume that the web PHP is running with the same permissions on the executable and target file as your ssh session. This is not a valid assumption.

And thirdly, you assume that it is safe to spawn a child process of daemon and [expect it to be isloated](http://symcbean.blogspot.co.uk/2010/02/php-and-long-running-processes.html) from the parent process. This is not a valid assumption.

None of that explains why the file is being created with the contents you describe - which makes me think the file you are looking at was NOT created by the code you've shown us.

Comment: Thank you for pointing all of that out.  You article is helpful.  I still could not make that work.  I tried this command:
echo /usr/bin/php .../www/example/phpbg-back.php \& > .../www/example/phpbg-out.txt | /usr/bin/at now 2&>&1 

I removed part of the path to post this, but that should fix the assumption about the path.

Permissions doesn't seem to be an issue; it's creating the file.

Now it is using the at service to run the process.

Still it runs the current page rather than the one I specify.  Do you see anything that I am missing?